# Entity Framework updates only 50% of transactions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework to update some fields in my project table

```
public class Project
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    //more fields here ....
    public bool Activated{ get; set; }
    public bool IsReady{ get; set; }
    public bool IsSpecialProject{ get; set; }

    public IList<ProjectDetail> ProjectDetails{ get; set; }
}
```

My project has many details

```
public class ProjectDetail
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Project Project{ get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid ProjectId{ get; set; }             
    public string DetailDescription{ get; set; }  
}
```

I am trying to update the three bool fields

```
var ProjectInDb = _dbContext.Project.Where(.....).FirstOrDefault();

if (ProjectInDb == null) 
    return false;            

ProjectInDb.Activated = true;
ProjectInDb.IsReady= true;         
ProjectInDb.IsSpecialProject= true; 

var x = _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

My problem is that this code sometimes updates the fields and sometimes not. I mean, one time it does so, another time it does not, then it does and so on.

What do you think is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Any errors/exceptions?

Comment: If no property value is changed (for instance, if the next time you do set the 3 properties from the example to `true` again), EF is smart enough to not issue `UPDATE` command. Is this what you are referring as "sometimes updates, sometimes not"?

Comment: May be there data issue in db. I never ever face such type of issue.

Comment: @RuiJarimba no errors...

Comment: @IvanStoev  well...it is so strange because when I first create a record in the Project table, the properties are set to false...

Comment: @AsifRaza I will check again everything, using the Sql server profiler